# Notice more Geomatics questions than GIS specific.

Tags: discussion, faq-suggestion

Should this site concern more geomatics questions?  The only problem with geomatics, is no one knows what geomatics is, but everyone knows GIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this is something that should go in the FAQ?

> This site is for answering questions related to all things GIS, Geomatics, remote sensing, &c.

Answer (score 4):

I only talk about geomatics with canadians, but even then it's hit or miss if they've heard of the word. To tell you the truth, I've been working for companies and agencies with "geomatics" in their name for almost twenty years, and it's in my job title, but I still can't give a definition without mental scrabbling. :)

Comment: Exactly.  People ask me what my education is, and I say Geomatics.  They go: what's that?  I say.  "Geo": Earth, "matics": like mathematics; the art and science of Measuring the earth.  It doesn't work.  We should go back saying surveying, but then that gets confused with Census Surveys.

Answer (score 2):

I think part of the reason for this is the large number of stackoverflow users (read programmers) involved in the beta.  Once the site is established and we see more non-programmer GIS types get involved I would expect this to change.

Comment: I would consider myself one of the few GIS folks who are not programmers. I'm a civil engineer and although, I'm not bad with python, I found there is a lot more programming related questions on GIS.se than what I see my GIS folks at the office do. Needless to say. I'm surprised we haven't seen any true surveying questions pop up